# Does Matlab uses any reordering algorithm in computing the inverse using "inv"

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I am trying to use Matlab biult-in function "inv" to compute inverse of a square matrix. Does matlab inv() use any reordering algorithm (inside inv and with out specifying by the user) to compute inverse?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [There are good reasons not to use inverse](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/). Be aware.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably row pivoting going on to minimize round-off, but that's just part of the algorithm.

The inverse that you get back should be in the expected order.  Are you asking because there's an unusual feature that you can't explain?

I'll ask why you think you need the inverse.  It's more typical to solve equations using LU decomposition and forward-back substitution rather than computing the full inverse.  How are you using the result?

Comment: Thanks @duffymo for the quick response. In my algorithm, I need to compute 4 matrix times matrix multiplication, something looks like this A*(inv(B))*C*D; where A,B,C and D are square matrices an B = B1*B2. And all the matrix initially are sparse matrices. But this multiplication makes dense.

Comment: I assume that @duffymo's reasoning is that `A*(inv(B))*C*D`  will be much more efficient as `A/B*C*D`, and will provide the same answer (to within expected precision).  I'll do some quick timing ...

Comment: +1 BTW for determining the actual question behind the question.

Comment: What do you know, timing shows not much difference.  Not what I expected.  Of course the precision concern from the link is still valid.

Comment: Thanks Pursuit for the responses. Also, I did see some wiered behavior of Inv() for rank deficient matrices. I have an nxn symmetrical matrix, but singular. I see the rank of the matrix is (n-2). But when I take the inverse of the matrix, MATLAB does not complain that this matrix is singular. Does Inv() behave similar to pinv()?